# Closing a dialog from the parent component

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js, vue-cli-3

I am using Vue.js and Vuetify and i am having trouble in closing a dialog box.

i have set a dialog `= ''` and altering the value on method using `this.dialog = false.`

```
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
            <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
                <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">Open Dialog</v-btn>
            </template>
            <v-card>
                <v-card-actions>
                    <div class="flex-grow-1"></div>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Close</v-btn>
                    <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="save">Save</v-btn>
                </v-card-actions>
            </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
```

Comment: you can use `v-show` or `v-if`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set dialog to false just like in the example and then change the state whenever you click the button.

[image]